# javascriptの「コンソールに値が返る」について

Tags: javascript

かなりしょうもない質問なのですが確証が欲しくて質問します。

[カンマ演算子の説明](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)に

```
a = b = 3, c = 4; // コンソールに 4 が返る
console.log(a); // 3 (もっとも左)
```

というものがありますが、
当たり前の話ですが以下のようにしてhtmlに埋め込んでもコンソール自体に値が返るのは、console.logの部分だけです。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

a = b = 3, c = 4; // コンソールに 4 が返る
console.log(a); // 3 (もっとも左)

-->
```

勿論直接コンソールに

```
a = b = 3, c = 4; // コンソールに 4 が返る
```

を打ち込めば値は返ってきます。

つまり、こういったサンプルコードはコンソールに直接打ち込む事を想定して書いているという事でいいのでしょうか？(htmlにjavascriptを埋め込んだときには値はコンソールには表示されないので)

Comment: コンソールでの実行を想定しているというよりは、コンソールで実行すると式の評価結果が確認できるということでしょうね。カンマ演算子を使った式の結果が欲しいならば`result=(a = b = 3, c = 4);`として`result`を使用すればいいですしね。

Comment: 確かに「コンソールに 4 が返る」は「コンソールだと評価結果が4だと確認できる」と解釈した方がしっくりきますね。有難うございました。

Comment: 正解が出しづらい内容(書いた人しか分からない)なので、納得できた意見を自己回答として投稿後、承認してはいかがでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myakuさんの提案があったのでBLUEPIXYさんのコメントを参考に自己回答しておきます。

MDNの「コンソールに4が返る」というのは、「サンプルコードをコンソールで実行する事を期待している」というよりは、単純に「コンソールだと評価結果が4だと確認できる」という解釈で良い。

また、カンマ演算子を使った式の評価結果が欲しい場合は

```
console.log((a = b = 3, c = 4))
```

のように括弧で括って引数を渡してやれば良い。